# Extract YouTube video ID from embed URL within iFrame tags

Tags: regex

I have a certain amount of content like this:

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ullamcorper enim ut nulla fringilla, non elementum nunc dapibus. Donec porta a lorem in vestibulum. Aenean viverra vulputate finibus. Sed malesuada nibh vitae enim luctus, at placerat diam vehicula.</strong></p>

<p>Quisque eu nisl sed tellus congue aliquet ac id risus. Etiam eget nisi ac lectus cursus suscipit. Mauris a dictum justo. Aliquam eget mi vel nunc imperdiet ultricies.</p>

<iframe width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EgqUJOudrcM" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>
```

All I am trying to do is get the YouTube video ID.

So far, I have come up with the following Regular Expression:

```
/<iframe.*src=["\'].*youtube\.com\/embed\/(.*)["\'] ?>/
```

This works if the `src` attribute is the last attribute in the tag, otherwise it doesn't. How can my regular expression be written so as to overcome this?

[Works in this case](https://regex101.com/r/bC6sF9/1)

[But not in this one](https://regex101.com/r/bC6sF9/2)

As you can see, in the second example, my Regex also matches the attribute after `src`. I know *why* this happens, I just can't work out how to prevent it.

I'm certainly no Regex expert, so any suggestions to improve what I currently have are welcome.

Comment: Why do you try to match the iframe, just find the youtube embed url ?

Comment: @Cyrbil There could be an embed URL within a paragraph somewhere else in the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this one:

```
<iframe.*?src=".*?youtube\.com\/embed\/(\w+)
```

The `.*?` avoid matching to much and stop on first `src` attribute
Then it match the url straightforward.

Edit: You just want the id, not full url

Comment: I added `["']` to allow for either single or double quotes but this seems to work perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
<iframe[^>]*src=\"[^\"]+\/([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>
```